# AndroidX BiometricPrompt on devices running Android 9 and lower

Tags: android, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

When using the BiometricPrompt with `setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true)` and then doing multiple failed fingerprint auths, I would expect the device to fallback to requesting PIN/pattern to unlock the device. In my experience, no Android device below Android 10 actually does this.

What actually happens is that I receive the `ERROR_LOCKOUT` error on `onAuthenticationError` and then the fingerprint reader is disabled by the system. Which means that even though I have a "Login with fingerprint" button in the UI, it won't do anything after user has failed to authenticate multiple times.

On my OnePlus 7 Pro running Android 10, the behaviour is correct; after multiple failed authentication attempts, the dialog asks for the PIN. Using AndroidX Biometrics, I would expect the same behaviour to happen on older devices too. Or am I mistaken?

Edit: Created bug report about this to Google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148045413